# Javascript regex on input name

Tags: javascript, regex

I have inputs with names:

```
<input type="text" name="data[Site][search]">
<input type="text" name="data[Site][name]">
```

I want to get when I click only:

```
search
name
etc.
```

My JS in click event

```
var reg = /data\[Site\]\[\d\]/g;
var test = $(this).attr("name").match(reg);
console.log(test);
```

But console display `null`. What is wrong in my reg?

Answer (score 2):

Try with using this:

```
var reg = /data\[Site\]\[(.+)\]/g;          //Capture the characters between []
var test = reg.exec($(this).attr("name"));
console.log(test[1]);                       //Output search | name
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g55vZ/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You're using `\d` which means digits only, you're also not specifying a quantifier so you'll only capture one digit at most, i.e:

`data[Search][1]`

You could use `\S` which is any non-whitespace character. You want to do this for at least one character (as you shouldn't have `data[Search][]` and you'll also want to capture the name, so throw in some `()`. You could switch `\S` to specific characters using character sets, for example `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Anyhow, your modified example should not look something like this:

```
var reg = /data\[Site\]\[(\S+)\]/g;
var test = $(this).attr("name").match(reg);

console.log(test);
```

You'll be able to pull the actual value from the match captures using `test[1]`.

Comment: Thank you, I have a question. how can I display only this string? Now in console have: ["data[Site][search]"]    I want only search

Comment: Try `console.log(test[1])`